# jQuery ajax get failing, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hitting this url responds with some JSON: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

Attempting to capture that response with a jQuery GET as follows:

```
$.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Fails. In Firebug, I'm seeing status 200 OK, but red, as if there was a 404 or 500 or some other error code, and no response. Does anyone know what is going on here and why?

Header info:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sun, 27 Apr 2014 18:02:42 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=6e7d53687d98f8a492c8d7f8e07d9718; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1

Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host    poloniex.com
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
```

Comment: I think to say because of the SOP, and because there is _no_ CORS implemented, would be a little more precise ;-)

Comment: So basically what I'm gathering from skimming Google results is that it will not be possible for me to retrieve the data without some sort of proxy server? Can't just pull it in from JavaScript due to their server's policy?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, so that it may help others. There turns out to be a relatively simple workaround for this. You can use a quick and dirty PHP file that will serve as a proxy for the AJAX request:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
echo $file;
?>
```

Now instead of hitting the url directly, call to the proxy and pass in the requrl argument:

```
$.get('proxy.php', { requrl: 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker' }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```